# tinyMCE удаляет первый слэш

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

Вызываю в функции вот так

```
tinymce.init(Object.assign({}, window.config.tinymce.full))
```

В настройка инициализации редактора пишу

```
config = {
  app: null,
  tinymce: {
    full: {
      selector: '.tinymce.en',
      language: 'ru',
      convert_urls : false,
      theme: 'modern',
      plugins: 'print preview searchreplace autolink directionality visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount imagetools contextmenu colorpicker textpattern code',
      toolbar1: 'bold italic forecolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat | code',
      image_advtab: true,
      templates: [
        { title: 'Шаблон описания 1', content: '<p>Шаблон описания 1</p>' },
        { title: 'Шаблон описания 2', content: '<p>Шаблон описания 2</p>' }
      ],
      menubar: 'edit insert view format table',

      width: '100%',
      height: 400,
      setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
          editor.save()
        })
      }
   }
}
```

А эта св...чь все равно удаляет первый слэш из урла,когда я пытаюсь вставить картинку, как быть,подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Удаляет откуда?

Comment: Когда пытаюсь вставить картинку

Comment: ОТКУДА удаляет? В картинках нет слэша.

Comment: из урла по которому находится картинка